# Responsive full width div insert in CSS Display Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, css-grid

```
.grid-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
  }
  .grid-content > div > div > div {
    background: black;
    display: grid;
  }
  
  .grid-content > div > div > div::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
```

the grid has the div class `grid-content` and the items in it have a div class `clickable_item`

Clicking on any item on the grid will move this div block to below that selected item. This div occupies the full width of the row and needs to adjust its `grid-column: 1 / span n` property to stay responsive to the number of row columns in the grid.

Currently the `grid-column 1 / span 8` property is fixed and doesnt dynamically adjust to changing columns in the wrapping grid.

Items should have a unique id and also must show or hide a full width div below its row when it is clicked

https://codepen.io/ridhwaans/pen/jOrpeNW

update: using

```
gridComputedStyle.getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns").replace(' 0px', '').split(' ').length;
```

from a resize listener to update style property.
The full width div messes with other items during wrapping in the codepen demo. How do I move the div every time to span the columns in grid?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/VwjBqVd

Basically, use the function [insertAdjacetElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) which will allow you to insert an element in the position of your choosing.

And also note, you need to traverse the DOM in this case so:

`e.target.parentElement.parentElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', some_node)`

Comment: its not responsive. I need to move the div to the last column in the grid as it resizes